# Finding a channel by name then sending a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been searching everywhere for how to find a channel then send a message to it all in the guildCreate event. So far this is my code:

```js
    client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
        console.log("Joined server!");
        guild.channels.create("text-channel", {type: 'text'});
        client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "text-channel").send("Hello");
})
```

When I use this I get the error: `cannot send property send of undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "text-channel").send("Hello");` does not work because `client.channels` are mapped by their IDs, not names.

You need to either use:

1. `guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "text-channel").send("Hello");` instead of `client.channels`

OR

  2.

```js
guild.channels.create("text-channel", {type: 'text'}).then((channel) => channel.send("Hello");
```

Comment: Number 1 still gives me the same error, but number 2 it worked :) Thanks so much!